# Ubuntu takes too long to boot (almost 2 minutes)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, lts

I have a Acer Aspire 5741G and I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS recently. I have windows 7 pro as the other OS (dual boot). I get really slow boot times. It takes roughly 2 minutes to show all the icons on my desktop.

When I try running 
 *systemd-analyze* , it shows around a minute mostly (screenshot attached). Screenshot for *systemd-analyze blame* also attached. Can the boot time be possibly reduced? Also, my screen flashes few times before the purple loading screen while booting. After some searches, people said it has something to do with the graphic card. Can I make this right?
Thanks 
[image: first image]
[image: second image]
[image: third image]
[image: fourth image]]

Comment: I don't see any screenshots.

Comment: @AndroidDev Sorry, didn't see that. Updated now

Comment: @abdrk00 your screenshots didn't work. But i've fixed that now

Comment: Is sda7 your root partition? Do you know how to `fsck -f /` or `fsck -f /dev/sda7` from recovery mode/root access?

Comment: @heynnema  yes, sda7 is my root partition. sorry, i dont know how to do that :/

Comment: see my answer, below...

Answer (score 1):

Lets check the file system to make sure there aren't any errors.

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery Mode
- choose root access
- type `sudo fsck -f /`
- run fsck more than once if there were errors
- optional

  - open `terminal` from the Unity dash
  - type `grep sda7 /var/log/syslog*`
  - look for errors
  - copy/paste output into paste.ubuntu.com and give us the URL
- type `reboot`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23693642/     (link for the grep command).  Here's the link to the fsck command- http://imgur.com/a/3mjbM   (I used imgur as I don't know how to add images here. Sorry)

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk` and `swapon`

Comment: ps: Make sure to put `@heynnema` at the beginning of any new comment directed to me, or I might not see it. Let me know when you've done the above commands.

Comment: The output screenshot has been added to the question.

Comment: Everything looks fine. I'm at a loss. Is your BIOS up to date with version 1.23? If not, go to https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/2058?b=1 and download the newest BIOS from there and install it. I'd recommend making a good backup of your important files before installing it. It never hurts to be safe.

Comment: I updated and still getting similar boot times. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I don't have any more suggestions, but what you should concentrate on is 1) why the swap disk timed out during your second fsck, and 2) why blame shows the same startup cycle 3 times. 2 minutes is too long to boot.

Comment: You could `grep sda6 /var/log/syslog*`  and `grep swap /var/log/syslog*` and see if your swap partition is logging errors. You could also run `Disks` app and run the SMART diagnostics on your hard disk.

Comment: The commands show no errors.